# how to add progress message in google home dialogflow

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

In my conversation dialogflow, I would like to add some progress messages like `hang in with me, I'm looking up for that data` or similar in the conversation. Is there any guidance or best practice to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no good way to do this at this time. If your webhook takes longer than about 5 seconds, Dialogflow will return one of the default responses it is set with. If you're not using Dialogflow, the Action SDK will say your webhook isn't responding and will close the conversation.

There is currently no way to send a reply, and then send another reply without the user saying something first.

One workaround might be to have the default response be something like "I'm looking that information up. Ask me again in a few seconds." When your lookup finally completes, cache the information so when/if the user asks the question again, you can return it more quickly.

Depending how long it takes, you may also wish to register a [dynamic reprompt](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts). This will send an event to your webhook if the user doesn't say anything. In a situation like this, they may say nothing for a few seconds, but that may be long enough for you to have computed the reply. So after a few seconds of silence you can suddenly announce "I've figured it out, the answer you were looking for is..." or something similar. This has some limitations - you can only reprompt twice like this before Google sends you a final reprompt and closes the conversation.

Although the platform does support [notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates), these are still in developer preview and don't work with all devices. They also don't quite continue the conversation (it doesn't just start talking) - they just send a notification to a phone that there is a message and that they can restart the conversation. Depending on your use case, this may be useful combined with the above.

**Update**

The [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) includes a feature that we can take advantage of to handle this. Similar to the dynamic reprompt method above, you'll get a call automatically when the media you're playing ends. So you can play a short "hold music" and your webhook will be called when it is finished. You can then either give the result or say you're still working on it and play more hold music.